How to refresh AVPlayer Header authorization token when token expires
I am trying to play the protected HLS streams and the authorization token expires in 5 minutes,I am trying to achieve this with 'AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate' and I'm getting an error 401 Unauthorized.
The question is how to update the token inside asset? I've already tried to change it in resourceLoader loadingRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields but it is not working:
class ResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
var originalURL: URL
var token: String
init(originalURL: URL, token: String) {
self.originalURL = originalURL
self.token = token
}
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
        guard let url = loadingRequest.request.url else {
            loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: "Invalid URL", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
            return false
        }
        
        // Create a URLRequest with the initial token
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = loadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields
        // Perform the request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error performing request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "HTTP Error", code: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? -1, userInfo: nil)
                print("HTTP Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: error)
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
            }
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }
        
        task.resume()
        return true
}


Any help would be highly appreciated. I am also facing the same issue.
